# Cosa significa "inciarpato"?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto questo testo che descrive l'incontro in Inghilterra della pittrice con la regina Enrichetta di Francia, sposa del re Carlo I d'Inghilterra:

> Sospirava Artemisia, e in un rimescolio poco solenne fece il suo ingresso Enrichetta. Marciava alla scudiera come avesse il frustino sulla coscia, figurava senza collo fra tutti quei riccioli finti. Dietro, le brache **inciarpate** dei francesi, rosse, bianche, giallette; le francesi dipinte; preti, frati in copia, colla cintola o senza, bianchi neri violetti e berrettini.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "inciarparto", ma non l'ho trovato nei dizionari. Ho visto però che appare anche nel libro *La vita di Giulio Pane* di Giulio Tanini, che si può leggere su [Liber Liber](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/t/tanini/la_vita_di_giulio_pane/pdf/tanini_la_vita_di_giulio_pane.pdf). Si trova in questo brano:

> I «*Vicoli Duchessa*», perchè erano dieci o dodici, I, II, III, IV ecc. erano veramente curiosi; piccole botteguccie non più grandi d'una cantina; nere, sudice, e dove si vendeva d'ogni cosa un po', pesce e
>   aranci, maccheroni e peperoni fritti, radici e cedri; un miscuglio
>   di mille oggetti disparati, messi fuori delle porte, sulle scale fetide
>   e **inciarpate**; e fra le robe sciorinate, le facce dei marmocchi, le
>   camice da donna, le vecchie camiciole, le ciabatte, le granate e le
>   poltrone!

Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato di "inciarpato"?

Comment: Secondo il *Vocabolario Senese* di Ubaldo Cagliaritano, il verbo *inciarpare* significa *mettere in disordine*, per cui interpreterei *inciarpato* come *disordinato*. Non ho la minima idea dell'affidabilità della fonte (è il risultato di una ricerca di *inciarpare* su google) ma sembra coerente con gli esempi presentati

Comment: Mai sentito, ma partirei dai due significati di “[ciarpa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tag/ciarpa/)”, pensando che per il tuo primo esempio forse è più pertinente il primo (collegato con “sciarpa”), mentre per le scale fetide di sicuro il secondo (presumibilmente nel senso di “piene di detriti”). Oggi “ciarpa” è molto poco usato; “ciarpame” appena appena di più.

Comment: Anna Banti utilizza questo termine anche per definire uno studioso nell'articolo da lei scritto su OGGI il 3 giugno 1939.
Scrive: "Uno dei più pericolosi è questo archivista giovane, un ometto inciarpato, raffreddato, miope che si danna l’anima alla ricerca di un introvabile testamento cinquecentesco..." Io non ho idea di cosa significhi, ma forse *un ometto disordinato* può funzionare.

Answer (score 2):

Nel saggio *[Il "viale" e lo "stradone". Appunti sulla lingua dei romanzi, in "Il Giannone", 27-28, 2016, Omaggio ad Anna Banti](https://www.academia.edu/33223387/Il_viale_e_lo_stradone_._Appunti_sulla_lingua_dei_romanzi_in_Il_Giannone_27-28_2016_Omaggio_ad_Anna_Banti)* di Margherita Quaglino, si può leggere:

> **inciarpato** (415) 'avvolto come da una sciarpa', variante etimologica
> di insciarpare;

Le brache dei francesi quindi presentavano una sorta di fascia sui fianchi.

Answer (score 1):

Controllando i vari significati in diversi dizionari etimologici sono finito al significato di fascia, bandoliera ecc.
Una ricerca per "inciarpati" mi porta risultati dove il significato è "con la sciarpa". Per esempio (Il Bel Paese di A. Stoppani):

> In genere però, tutti hanno una gran smania di correre; tutti sono più affaccendati del solito, e tiran diritto intabarrati, incappottati, incappucciati, inciarpati,

Attorno al periodo della Gentileschi la moda francese usava una fascia alla vita tipo cintura. Una ricerca piazza la moda attorno alla metà del '600. In quel senso "brache inciarpate" sarebbero pantaloni con la fascia alla cinta.
Nel secondo brano invece direi che si intende più come "piene di ciarpame" come indicano DaG e Denis Nardin nel commento alla domanda.

Answer (score 1):

Credo che il termine *inciarpato* venga utilizzato con due significati diversi nei due contesti; in entrambi i casi la parola su cui focalizzare l'attenzione è *ciarpa*.

- Nel primo caso si fa appello al [significato letterale](http://www.etimo.it/?term=sciarpa) di *ciarpa*:
  [image]

  (*«Lunga fascia di seta e con nappe,»* etc.): dunque "inciarpato" starebbe a significare "munito di *ciarpa*", dove si adotta il termine col significato precedente.
- Nel secondo caso, invece, il verbo *inciarpare* viene utilizzato con il [significato](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.xeniaeditrice.it/vernacolosiocrpdf.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi9sofs0fLKAhUEuxQKHfBgAy4QFggmMAM&usg=AFQjCNFa9J5QSl9LcQr9USx-K8WzGbrxSA&sig2=4mofprtVq0xwnLzOtbNZnw) di "mettere in disordine"; l'uso di *ciarpa*, qui, è per estensione e nel senso di "cosa vecchia divenuta inutile e senza pregio". Le "scale inciarpate" sarebbero quindi scale piene di *ciarpe*, con il termine utilizzato in questa seconda accezione.